# Pass function parameter of undefined type pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have references to dynamically loaded dll's function. Before calling them I need to make universal function that compares they are not equal to null? How to define undefined type parameter in my case?

I do :

```
boolean canLoad(void value)
{
    if (!value)
    {
        LogIt("could not locate the function");
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

But compiler is not happy about `void` .

Comment: something like `template <typename T> bool canLoad(T *value) { return value != nullptr; }`: http://ideone.com/rg0Bli

Answer (score 3):

`void` means *no type* or for argument lists *no arguments*. If you want a generic pointer then that is `void *`.

***But*** it's better to have *templates* instead as that will make it more type-safe.

Also it's better to be explicit (i.e. `value == nullptr` as the condition, though this is kind of subjective), and use proper standard types (what is `boolean`?)

Comment: I recently used the same argument in a discussion, but tbh I wonder in what way is a template more type safe than a `void*` method in this case?